# Creating a view from another Server error

Tags: sql-server

Hi All I am trying to create a View from another database server...
I have have got server A an din Server A is where i want to create a view referencing a table from Server B.... when I run the command below:

```
create view TableFromServerB as select * from ServerB.master.information_schema.table;
```

I get the following error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerB" returned
>   message "Login timeout expired". OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server "ServerB" returned message "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books
>   Online.". Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Named Pipes Provider:
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

I have done some research online and i came to a source that suggested using `sp_addlinkedserver` in my command .. which i have done and when i did this it said server already exists . So is there anything i am missing out here??

Comment: Can you list the results from `select * from sys.servers` ?

Comment: yup ... the server i am trying to reference from is actually listed as well ...

Comment: can you actually run the statement `select * from ServerB.master.information_schema.table` ?

Comment: I think the table you want would be ServerB.master.information_schema.tables`.  The name is plural ("tableS", not "table").

Comment: @horie .. that command gave me the same error i'm afraid :S .. Gordon .. that didn't work either

Comment: @SomuchtoLearn, add linked server is a one-time operation that can be done either with T-SQL (sp_addlinked_server) or the SSMS GUI.  You should be able to reference the remote table with 4-part names after you create the linked server.

Comment: a) can you ping the target server, b) do you have the appropriate security credentials on linked server ? The message you got points me towards those potential problems

Answer (score 2):

I have seen an issue like this before:
Can you please do something like this:

1. Create a view in your linked server to access the object i.e `master.information_schema.table;`
2. Use this view in the queries from the server where you want to display the results.

Eg:

```
--- create view script--
create view dbo.vINFORMATION_SCHEMATABLES
as
SELECT     *
FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
go

-- select statement from local server
select * from [testSRV].[testDB_far].[dbo].[vINFORMATION_SCHEMATABLES]
```

Let me know if this helps.